# Get the row with highest value of a column when they all share same dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on an inventory search system, and one of the features is returning all rows that fall within a date range.

The thing is, there are multiple rows that share the same date, but each ID is unique and different. The higher the ID, the later the entry.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
id, date, item1, item2, ....
1, 8-11-2018, 10, 10, ...
2, 8-11-2018, 10, 10, ...
3, 8-11-2018, 10, 10, ...
4, 8-13-2018, 10, 10, ...
5, 8-13-2018, 10, 10, ...
6, 8-14-2018, 10, 10, ...
```

So, if my date range was from 8-11-2018 to 8-14-2018, the rows that would be returned are `3, 8-11-2018, 10, 10, ...`, `5, 8-13-2018, 10, 10, ...`, and `6, 8-14-2018, 10, 10, ...`.

I tried some stuff with `groupby`, but none of those ways worked.

The only way I can think of is to separate the "main dataframe" to smaller dataframes that have the same date, then sort it by ID, but this just seems like a terrible way to do it.

How should I go about solving this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('id').drop_duplicates('date',keep='last')
```

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` your `date` column, use `idxmax` to get the row ids you need, and use `iloc` to access your desired rows:

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('date').id.idxmax()]

   id       date  item1  item2
2   3  8-11-2018     10     10
4   5  8-13-2018     10     10
5   6  8-14-2018     10     10
```